# Using MVC Controller Function to Fill Text as 'Name' & Values as 'Id' in Dropdownlist without using a model

Tags: c#, powershell, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a function in my controller file that loads the details of AD Groups using System.Management.Automation library. Creating the instance of PowerShell & Executing the script. I am fetching 2 attributes of the Groups, Name & GUID, I want to reference the Name to the Text field of the dropdownlistitem & GUID To the Value field. Here's my Code in C#:

```
 public ActionResult GroupReview()
    {
       ViewBag.Groups = PowerShellExecutorLst(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Shell\\Get-ADStewardGroups.ps1");
 }

 public List<SelectListItem> PowerShellExecutorLst(string scriptPath)
    {
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
        var listItemStr = new List<String>();
        shell.Commands.AddCommand(scriptPath);
        var results = shell.Invoke();
        if (results.Any())
        {
            foreach(var psObj in results)
            {
                listItemStr.Add(Server.HtmlEncode(psObj.ToString().Trim('@', '{', '}')));
            };
        }
        List<SelectListItem> listItems = listItemStr.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text=s }).ToList();
        shell.Dispose();
        return listItems;
    }
```

Here's My HTML Code To Fill DropDownList:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="width:auto">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlGroup", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Groups, "Select Group", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

Here's the PowerShell Script That I am Passing

```
Get-ADGroup -Properties Name, ObjectGUID | Select Name, ObjectGUID
```

I am able to get the data as needed just trying to bifurcate Name & GUID into Text & Value field of DropDownList respectively.[image]

Comment: You are not able to get the `Name` and `ObjectGUID` in your `SelectListItem` property for `Name` and `Value`?

Comment: I am confused in this line : List<SelectListItem> listItems = listItemStr.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text=s }).ToList();

Comment: So every SelectListItem needs to be binded correctly with a corresponding `Key-Value` pair. Think of it as a `Dictionary`. In order for a successful bind, the `Text` and `Value` parameters are required when creating a new `SelectListItem`. In your case, I believe that the `Name` would be mapped to `Text` and `ObjectGUID` will be mapped to `Value`. From the looks of it, you are setting both to variable `s` which can give you incorrect result. Your `listItemStr` is returning one string value. You would have to break this string into `Name` and `ObjectGUID` and then assign it to  `SelectListItem`